# Creating a Mac OSX bundle from a Java program

Tags: java, macos, bundle, executable

Let's assume that I wrote a simple Java program, that is the file ending with .java that I can compile with javac, and then run with java...

How do I create a Mac OSX executable (.app) bundle, so that I can send it to others who will then be able to launch it on their Macs with a double click?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=mac%20app%20from%20jar&oq=mac%20app%20from%20ja&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3051j0j1

Comment: I had a look indeed... most of the info is a bit outdated...

Comment: You can have a look at this answer: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html

Answer (score 1):

What you should check is [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html), especially the parameter **native** and its value **image**

```
javapackager -deploy -native image -appclass fqn.of.MyClass -srcfiles /path/to/my.jar
```

> `-native type`
>
> Generate self-contained application bundles (if possible). Use the -B
>   option to provide arguments to the bundlers being used. If type is
>   specified, then only a bundle of this type is created. If no type is
>   specified, all is used.
>
> The following values are valid for type:
>
> **all**: Runs all of the installers for the platform on which it is
>   running, and creates a disk image for the application. This value is
>   used if type is not specified.
>
> **installer**: Runs all of the installers for the platform on which it is
>   running.
>
> **image**: Creates a disk image for the application. On OS X, the image is
>   the .app file. On Linux, the image is the directory that gets
>   installed.
>
> **dmg**: Generates a DMG file for OS X.
>
> **pkg**: Generates a .pkg package for OS X.
>
> **mac.appStore**: Generates a package for the Mac App Store.
>
> **rpm**: Generates an RPM package for Linux.
>
> **deb**: Generates a Debian package for Linux.